# Android: how to get text height

Tags: android

I have a `String text = "Some text"`.

Now I need do know what the height of the text will be if I put it in a TextView with for example `width = x dp` and `height = y dp`.

For example in iOS I can do like this:

```
CGSize size = [self.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 10000)
                            lineBreakMode:0];
```

`Paint.getTextBounds()` will not work here, because it will not brake text to lines.

Comment: You want to get the height of the text, after setting the text in a textview with a specified height?

Comment: Actually, before I will set it to text view

Comment: I need to count text height, then I will know what height of text view should be

Comment: So you need to know how high the text will be, and then set the TextViews height accordingly? Why don't you just set Wrap Content on the TextViews height?

Comment: Because I have specific task, long story..

Comment: So you have a text string, a typeface, a size and a width of the text, and you want to know how high it is? I don't see why you couldn't just create a new TextView, and measure it (except maybe for performance, but that isn't necessarily a problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly set the height of the TextView to y dp then the height of the TextView in pixels will be `Math.round(y * density)`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density

If your TextView has been measured/laid out then [getMeasuredHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29) can be used to get the view height.

[Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) also has a number of methods to query about text properties